# How can I put a page of figures as the next to last page?

Tags: floats, positioning

Right now, at the end of my document I have my bibliography and then I do `\clearpage` followed by my 4 figures which occupy a page in total.  This figure page is the last page of my document.

However, I want these figures to appear as the page before the last page of my paper (the page which has the bibliography and last several paragraphs of text on it).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

@egreg's solution will work to flush the figures, but an alternative approach might be to ask *why* the figures are all stacked up and not coming out until your flush them with `\clearpage` or the end of the document. If there is enough material to fill a float page (and you haven't prevented float page positioning using the optional arguments) then it may be that setting the float algorithm parameters appropriately will allow the figures to be placed automatically without relying on the emergency flushout at the end of the document.

Comment: Good point - there may be a better way to set up floats to make this to occur properly in the first place. This is actually my first tex work and I was happy enough to get all 4 figures looking great on a page using \clearpage.. :)

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to load the `afterpage` package

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
```

and write, between two paragraphs that will fall in the next to last page,

```
\afterpage{\clearpage}
```

In this way, when the next to last page is shipped out, LaTeX will see the `\clearpage` command that will flush the figure queue.

There is no automatic mechanism to do so, I'm afraid. Do this only when you're sure that the text is in final form.